# R : Plotting Prediction Results for a multiple regression

Tags: r, line, regression, predict

I want to observe the effect of a treatment variable on my outcome Y. I did a multiple regression: `fit <- lm (Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)`. `x1` is the treatment variable and `x2`, `x3` are the control variables. I used the predict function holding `x2` and `x3` to their means. I plotted this predict function.

Now I would like to add a line to my plot similar to a simple regression `abline` but I do not know how to do this.

I think I have to use line(x,y) where `y = predict` and `x` is a sequence of values for my variable `x1`. But R tells me the lengths of `y` and `x` differ.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `termplot`:

```
## simulate some data
set.seed(0)
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
x3 <- runif(100)
y <- cbind(1,x1,x2,x3) %*% runif(4) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1)

## fit a model
fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)

termplot(fit, se = TRUE, terms = "x1")
```

[image]

`termplot` uses `predict.lm(, type = "terms")` for term-wise prediction. If a model has intercept (like above), `predict.lm` will centre each term ([What does predict.glm(, type=“terms”) actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37963904/4891738)). In this way, each terms is predicted to be 0 at the mean of the covariate, and the standard error at the mean is 0 (hence the confidence interval intersects the line at the mean).